# Bootstrap css for Printing prints in black and white only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **Bootstrap css** for printing purpose. It has css property as:

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    // Other code...
}
```

This is overriding all my css. I want to remove color from here(which prints in black and white) and use the color that I have described in original page. I do not want to remove this line from bootstrap css but rather want to redefine or undefine it using my own css or jquery as I will be able to update the **bootstrap css** if an update is available. Is it possible to explicitely delete the color.

Comment: Remove all of the `!important`.

Comment: Note that on top of your CSS definitions, browsers may also change the style of your page when printing (such as removing the background color). Make sure to inspect the page by viewing it in the print viewmode, instead of just judging by the print preview to be sure!

Answer (score 0):

you can customise the actual stylesheet that you get from bootstrap and simply not include the print section. You can go the their customize webpage (link below) and essentially choose what elementsare included. They will then create a compiled version of the css for you to download and include in the file.

This will mean that you would need to get a new  recompiled css at a later date from them, but it is better than trying to go in and delete content from the css.

checkout `http://getbootstrap.com/customize/`

Comment: Yes, that can be one solution. But I do not want to touch the bootstrap print css. As if new version of bootstrap is available then we might update it. So rather I would rather like to customize it on my own.